# I want to edit data without editing the email only edit another input field

Tags: php

basic email check is clear but if any user wants to update the data with same email Id then that message should not display....

```
if(isset($_GET['edited']))
     {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE  Id=".$_REQUEST['id']." ";
        //echo "SELECT * FROM user WHERE  Id=".$_REQUEST['id']."";
        $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        $user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $Id=$user['Id'];
        $name=$user['name'];
        $email=$user['email'];
        $gender=$user['gender'];
        $purpose=$user['purpose'];
        $MobileNumber=$user['MobileNumber'];
        $Status=$user['Status'];
}
```

Comment: Need to see your code.

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  echo 'Email is already exists!';
}
else
{
  if($_POST['txtid']=="0")
  {
    $sql="INSERT INTO user(name,email,gender,purpose,MobileNumber)Values('$name','$email','$gender','$purpose','$MobileNumber')";

Comment: if(isset($_GET['edited']))
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE  Id=".$_REQUEST['id']." ";
  //echo "SELECT * FROM user WHERE  Id=".$_REQUEST['id']."";

Comment: I'm unable to add my whole code that is why add some code line in comments

Comment: The email address you are using for testing, does it already exist in the database?  If it does that is why it is returning "Email already exists".  If you are wanting to then update the row that contains that email you need to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`

Comment: $query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  echo 'Email is already exists!';
}
else
{
  if($_POST['txtid']=="0")
  {
    $sql="INSERT INTO user(name,email,gender,purpose,MobileNumber)Values('$name','$email','$gender','$purpose','$MobileNumber')";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    
      $sql="UPDATE  user SET name='$name',email='$email',gender='$gender',purpose='$purpose',MobileNumber='$MobileNumber', Status='$Status' WHERE Id=".$_REQUEST['txtid']." ";

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have provided and not really understanding what you are trying to do, have a look at this and see if it helps.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) 
{ 
    echo 'Email is already exists!'; 
    $sql="UPDATE user SET name='$name',email='$email',gender='$gender',purpose='$purpo‌​se',MobileNumber='$M‌​obileNumber', Status='$Status' WHERE Id = ".$_REQUEST['txtid'];
} 
else 
{ 
    if($_POST['txtid']=="0") 
    { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name,email,gender,purpose,MobileNumber) values ('$name','‌​$email','$gender','$‌​purpose','$MobileNum‌​ber')"; 
    }
}
$query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
```

This is untested and I am not sure if you have provided all the code so you may need to edit it a bit before use.

The basic though is that the check for the existing email is completed, if that shows that there is an row containing that email address then you update the row with the new information.  The the email address is not in the database then insert it.